# Remove ability to save reports to public folders from Specific profiles

Tags: apex, custom-reports

We have an requirement where we don't users belonging to specific profile to save reports in the folder. Is there any way we can achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean any folder or a specific folder?  Please [edit] your post to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

Following profile System Permission's are provide the access to the users to save and view the reports in public folders.

> View Reports in Public Folders - View and access reports in public
> folders, which does not include others’ personal folders.

> Manage Reports in Public Folders - Create, edit, delete reports, and
> manage their sharing in all public folders.
>
> Above system permission required following system permissions,
>
> View Reports in Public Folders,  Create Report Folders,  Edit My
> Reports

So you can disable the "Manage Reports in Public Folders" permission for those specific profiles to restrict those users to save the reports in public folder.

Please let me know if it helps.